# Base64 encryption don't work on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, encryption, base64

I have create an app, which encrypts the incoming sms. It works fine on all API version, except on 4.2.2. The sms being encrypted, but it can't be decrypted...  I don't understand why this is happening. 4.2.4 use something different for encryption base64?

The app works fine for newest API.

This is the code:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;

public class StringCryptor 
{
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
private static final int RANDOM_KEY_SIZE = 128;

// Encrypts string and encode in Base64
public static String encrypt( String password, String data ) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] secretKey = generateKey( password.getBytes() );
    byte[] clear = data.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( clear );
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString( encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT );

    return encryptedString;
}

// Decrypts string encoded in Base64
public static String decrypt( String password, String encryptedData ) throws Exception 
{
    byte[] secretKey = generateKey( password.getBytes() );

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

    byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode( encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT );
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( encrypted );

    return new String( decrypted );
}

public static byte[] generateKey( byte[] seed ) throws Exception
{
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance( RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM );
    secureRandom.setSeed( seed );
    keyGenerator.init( RANDOM_KEY_SIZE, secureRandom );
    SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    return secretKey.getEncoded();
}
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what goes wrong?

Comment: The encrypted msg can't be decrypted. There are some errors.... javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted             at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:709)                        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1111)                        at org.secure.sms.StringCryptor.decrypt(StringCryptor.java:44)      at org.secure.sms.SecureMessagesActivity.onItemClick(SecureMessagesActivity.java:202)

Comment: This happened only in version 4.2.2....